# How to do firebase phone auth in a flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I've done all the steps to attach my database and proven I can get data that isn't protected by any auth rules.  Now I want to implement phone sign in and add auth rules.

`flutter doctor` and `flutter analyze` both return no errors.  I've copied the example code from [here, the firebase_auth plugin example code](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/example/lib/signin_page.dart)

The important point is here:

```
await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: _phoneNumberController.text,
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
    verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
    codeSent: codeSent,
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
}
```

When I run this line (iPhone simulator from VS code), I get no message on the console, the debug session ends, the simulator screen goes black, and seconds later returns to the home screen.

I'm new to all of this, but the only idea I have is this: when I print on the console `_auth.verifyPhoneNumber`, I get this

> Closure: ({String phoneNumber, Duration timeout, int
>   forceResendingToken, (AuthCredential) => void verificationCompleted,
>   (AuthException) => void verificationFailed, (String, [int]) => void
>   codeSent, (String) => void codeAutoRetrievalTimeout}) => Future
>   from Function 'verifyPhoneNumber':.

Notice that the third parameter is `int forceResendingToken`, which is not in my code.  I can't find any doc about this.

Two questions:
 1. Can you help me get auth working, and
 2. Can you help me navigate docs on my own?  In flutter, I don't know which firebase docs to look at.  Can you show me the link, for example, for the auth methods that should be used in flutter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that a simple URL scheme with just an array inside the item dictionary isn't the right format for firebase.  It must look like this:

[image]